# ‘json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 229 (char 676)’ error in python

Tags: python, json, import

I'm trying to import a json file that contains a list. heres the code. as i run it, i get the following error

```py
import json

with open("Sarcasm_Headlines_Dataset.json", "r") as f:
    datastore = json.load(f)
```

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 229 (char 676)
```

json file that i am using:

[{"article_link": "https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/versace-black-code_us_5861fbefe4b0de3a08f600d5", "headline": "former versace store clerk sues over secret 'black code' for minority shoppers", "is_sarcastic": 0},
{"article_link": "https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/roseanne-revival-review_us_5ab3a497e4b054d118e04365", "headline": "the 'roseanne' revival catches up to our thorny political mood, for better and worse", "is_sarcastic": 0},
{"article_link": "https://local.theonion.com/mom-starting-to-fear-son-s-web-series-closest-thing-she-1819576697", "headline": "mom starting to fear son's web series closest thing she will have to grandchild", "is_sarcastic": 1},]

Comment: could you also add the JSON or the relevant part?

Answer (score 0):

looks like your file is from https://www.kaggle.com/rmisra/news-headlines-dataset-for-sarcasm-detection/home.

they heave a **Reading the data** section that suggests this code:

```py
import json


def parse_data(file):
    for l in open(file, 'r'):
        yield json.loads(l)


datastore = list(parse_data('./Sarcasm_Headlines_Dataset.json'))
```

Comment: @AlirezaNourbakhsh if the code in my answer works, it means that the .json file is not a valid json at all, but each line is a document of its own. technically with .json files, your approach is the correct one (using `json.load` once and getting all the data)

Comment: i just found out the problem. there's was an additional comma before the list ends. solved it. thanks anyways